# Open Dialog Box (with Buttons) automatically when a Module is Opened

Tags: ibm-doors

I am looking for a couple suggestions on how to complete a couple of things. Every time someone opens a Module in my Doors Database, I want a dialog box to appear. The purpose of this is to have a more reliable database, and we can see why people are editing modules and when. I want the dialog box to have a couple of different functions:

1. It should list certain reasons for opening in button format, the user will click the reason they are opening the module.
2. If the reason for opening the module is to edit it, a separate window should open asking for the problem report number they are looking to address, or the reason for editing.
3. I would like to store the response in a database somewhere, like a log for that module, as to why it was opened, when, and by what user.

If anyone has any insight as to where I can look for solutions for this/any suggestions on my logic behind it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to DXL!

I think you're going to want to use a persistent trigger.

This is pretty simple, but like all simple things, can be dangerous.

```
Trigger t = trigger ( "t1" , project->all->module->all , pre , open , 10 , "#include <\\NETWORK PATH\Report.dxl>" )
```

This creates a trigger for the entire database, applied to all modules, that when a user attempts to open the module, Report.dxl is executed.

Note: the code above is untested (I don't want to dump a trigger across my entire database, so the syntax may be slightly off)

You would then want code in Report.dxl (which needs to be somewhere your users can access!) which accomplishes your goals:

1. Create a GUI with buttons
2. If Edit is selected, create another prompt
3. Open a stream and append to a log file whatever info you need

Let me know if you need assistance with those steps, and I'll try to offer what I can.

Comment: Hello, I would like to execute a button (export-----> plain text) using DXL. Is this function Trigger is useful in this case?